# Web app opens in browser on some devices

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, web-app

I have a few hardware-identical iPads with the same (latest) iOS version on them and on 2 out of around 10, a web app opens in the browser UI instead of the standalone UI. On all other iPads, it opens on the standalone UI as it's supposed to.

What are my options of making the two iPads behave like all the other ones? Is there anything other than resetting the whole iPad? Is there some cache for web app settings, that I can clear or so?

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

and a manifest.json:

```
{
 "name": "...",
 "display": "standalone",
 "icons": [
 ... ]
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what app/website you are referring to, in my experience with YouTube for example it seems to be pretty random when this happens.

Comment: @unknowndomain it's something private but I posted the relevant source code from the web app